# Has there ever been musical events or performances associated with deep-space spacecraft or their flyby maneuvers?

Tags: deep-space, identify-this-object, space-art

We've had several questions related to music being played (live, or recorded) in space:

- [Music played in space](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29913/12102) (6 answers)
- [How did Sergei Krikalev get (or build) the drum he is shown playing here?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30340/12102) (no answers yet)
- [Does the Apollo 10 “music” still occur on modern spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14166/12102) (no answers yet)
- [Is there really a radio on Elon Musk's solar-orbiting Tesla Roadster? Can we communicate with it?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24970/12102) (1 answer)
- [What sort of ambient air density was there when/were Starman/Roadster first started playing Bowie's “Life on Mars”](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30337/12102) (no answers yet)
- [What technical challenges would be playing this LP in (actual) space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17766/12102) (2 answers)
- Question about handling the delay when ISS crew and people on the ground perform together in a live musical event (I can't find this one but I know it's here somewhere)

We've also discovered [at least one beverage named after a deep space mission](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32661/12102).

But here I'd like to ask about specific musical events on earth connected to deep space spacecraft, *especially* those associated with notable events, such as flybys of solar system bodies.

**Question:** Have there ever been live musical events associated with deep-space spacecraft?

Comment: Hint: *recently?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes!

1. "It is Amazing, I am Amazed" by Craig Werth & the New Horizons Team:
2. Brian May - New Horizons (Ultima Thule Mix) [Official Music Video]